# How to count returned rows

Tags: php, sqlite

Using SQLITE3, how can I count the returned rows.

```
$results = $db->query('SELECT * FROM example WHERE _id = ' . $id);
while($row = $results->fetchArray()){
    $id = $row['_id'];
    $name = $row['name'];
}
```

Comment: You can count it in SQL, `SELECT COUNT(id) as numrows, * FROM..`. then access it as `$row['numrows']` after it's fetched.

Comment: @Qirel Thanks it works